# Ajax redirect to another page after success with POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to validate a form, I pass all the values with ajax to a php file where I valid some dates, after it is successful I need to redirect to another php file but with a POST, it is possible ?

I dont know if its the best way to do that so I'm open to any suggestions

This is my Ajax code:

```
$("form#Reservation").submit(function(){
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'confirmreservation.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {

        values=data.split('|');
        one=values[0];
        two=values[1];
        switch (one) 
        { 
            case '1': 
                // here I need something like this
                // POST(two) to payment.php
                break;
            case '2': 
                $("#reservation-fields" ).css("visibility","visible");
                break;
            case '3':
                $("#reservation-fields" ).css("visibility","hidden");
                $("#personal-fields" ).css("visibility","visible");
                break;                  
            case '4': 
                $("#personal-fields" ).css("visibility","hidden");
                $("#arrival-fields" ).css("visibility","visible");
                break;
            case '5': 
                $("#arrival-fields" ).css("visibility","hidden");
                $("#departure-fields" ).css("visibility","visible");
                break;
            case '6': 
                $("#departure-fields" ).css("visibility","hidden");
                $("#details-fields" ).css("visibility","visible");
                break;                                                       
            default:
            alert(data);
        }
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});

return false;
});
```

And this is my php file "confirmreservation.php"

```
<?php
require "conexion.php";
require "functions.php";

if ($_POST['service']==null||$_POST['destination']==null||$_POST['people']==null||$_POST['vehicle']==null)
{
    echo "2|0";
}
else
{

    if($_POST['service'] == 1)
    {
        if ($_POST['fname']==null||$_POST['lname']==null||$_POST['email']==null||$_POST['phone']==null)
        {
            echo "3|0";
        }
        else
        {

            if ($_POST['arrival-date']==null||$_POST['arrival-time']==null||$_POST['arrival-airline']==null||$_POST['arrival-flight']==null)
            {
                echo "4|0";
            }
            else
            {
                if ($_POST['departure-date']==null||$_POST['departure-time']==null||$_POST['departure-pick']==null||$_POST['departure-airline']==null||$_POST['departure-flight']==null)
                {
                    echo "5|0";
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($_POST['message']==null||$_POST['payment']==null)
                    {
                        echo "6|0";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $ID = 0;
                        $Consult = $Conexion->query('SELECT ID_Client FROM clients ORDER BY ID_Client DESC LIMIT 1');
                        while ($Fila = $Consult->fetch_assoc()) { 
                            $ID =  $Fila['ID_Client'] + 1; 
                        }
                        if($ID == 0){   $ID = 1; }  
                        if($_POST['lang'] == "sp") { 
                            $Arrival = Formato_es_to_date($_POST['arrival-date']); 
                            $Departure = Formato_es_to_date($_POST['departure-date']); 
                        } elseif($_POST['lang'] == "en") 
                        {
                            $Arrival = Formato_en_to_date($_POST['arrival-date']); 
                            $Departure = Formato_en_to_date($_POST['departure-date']); 
                        } 

                        $Conexion->autocommit(false);
                        $Queries=true; 

                        $Conexion ->query("INSERT INTO clients 
                            (ID_client,Client_fname,Client_lname,Client_email,Client_phone) VALUES 
                            ('".$ID."','".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['lname']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['phone']."')") ? null : $Queries=false;

                        $Conexion ->query("INSERT INTO reservation 
                            (Reserv_service,Reserv_destination,Reserv_people,Reserv_vehicle,Reserv_client,Reserv_arrival_date,Reserv_arrival_time,Reserv_arrival_airline,Reserv_arrival_flight,Reserv_departure_date,Reserv_departure_time,Reserv_departure_airline,Reserv_departure_flight,Reserv_departure_pick,Reserv_message,Reserv_payment) VALUES 

                            ('".$_POST['service']."','".$_POST['destination']."','".$_POST['people']."','".$_POST['vehicle']."','".$ID."','".$Arrival."','".$_POST['arrival-time']."','".$_POST['arrival-airline']."','".$_POST['arrival-flight']."','".$Departure."','".$_POST['departure-time']."','".$_POST['departure-airline']."','".$_POST['departure-flight']."','".$_POST['departure-pick']."','".$_POST['message']."','".$_POST['payment']."')") ? null : $Queries=false;

                        if($Queries == false)
                        {
                            $Conexion->rollback();
                            echo "Error, please contact the provider";
                        }

                        $Conexion->commit();
                        echo "1|".$ID;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

mysqli_close($Conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Use a regular form submit, it would redirect by default

Comment: Thank you for your reply @adeneo, you mean without ajax ?

Comment: How can I add alerts of empty fields ?, I didn't explain good, but on the case 1 is success, the other ones shows alerts of empty fields, that it the reason why I am using Ajax @adeneo

Comment: You could validate the dates client side using javascript, then if valid on the final condition post to the (second) PHP script

Comment: do you think is enough secure ? @KryptoniteDove I was thinking on validate on the server side

Comment: @PaulNoris It depends on the requirement, if you are simply validating the input is a valid date it should be fine assuming that you are protecting your DB from all user entered values as you should anyway. Do you want the page to refresh on the second post or to pass more data to a new script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical pattern would be :

```
$("form#Reservation").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    $.ajax({...}).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(data.valid) { // some test or other
            $("input#payment").val(data.someProperty); // put value in some (hidden) form field.
            form.submit(); // the form will submit in accordance with the <form> tag's action and method attributes.
        } else {
            $("#message").text('validation failed');
        }
    }, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#message").text(textStatus || errorThrown);
    });
});
```

Building your code on this pattern should be simple. You just need to make a few changes, eg ...

- flesh out the ajax params.
- replace my `if(...) {...} else {...}` with your switch/case structure.
- make sure your form has an `<input id="payment" />` field (or whatever).
- make sure your page has an `id="message"` element (or whatever).

If you don't want to submit the whole of the original form to "payment.php" then you can build/submit a separate (off-screen) form.